# How to reuse variables defined in root component in another component?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing an exercise for Full stack open course and had to Refactor the Content component so that it does not render any names of parts or their number of exercises by itself. Instead it only renders three Part components of which each renders the name and number of exercises of one part.

I can assign the same variables to Content but that increases the code.Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const Part = (props) => {
  return(
    <p>
      {props.part} {props.exercises}
    </p>
  )
}
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <h1>{props.course}</h1>
  )
}

const Content = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Part part={part1} exercises={exercises1}/>
      <Part part={part2} exercises={exercises2}/>
      <Part part={part3} exercises={exercises3}/>
    </div>
  )
}

const Total = (props) => {
  return(
    <p>Number of exercises {props.exercises}</p>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const course = 'Half Stack application development'
  const part1 = 'Fundamentals of React'
  const exercises1 = 10
  const part2 = 'Using props to pass data'
  const exercises2 = 7
  const part3 = 'State of a component'
  const exercises3 = 14

  return (
    <div>
      <Header course={course}/>
      <Content/>
      <Total exercises={exercises1+exercises2+exercises3}/>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: You can declare the `Content` function in the `App` function but it's ugly. Another way is to put those variables out of `App` so they will be in the module's scope so `Content` will have access to them. Or, just pass the variables and `Content` will be a stateless component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put the text and exercise counts in an array of objects:

```
const contentText = [
    { part: 'Fundamentals of React', exercises: 10 },
    { part: 'Using props to pass data', exercises: 7 }, 
    { part: 'State of a component', exercises: 14 }
];
```

Side note: If you want to get really modular, you can even put that in its own file and import it, but that's likely overkill here.

Then, you'll want to pass in that array as a prop for `Content`, let's call it `partArray`, so in `App`, you'll do this:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Header course={course}/>
      <Content partArray={contentText}/>
      ...
    </div>
  )
```

Side note: you'll also want to pass the right number into `Total`. Since you can't just add up three variables anymore, I would suggest using the [`reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to add up the numbers in `contentText`. That will be left as an exercise for the reader.

Lastly, you'll need to use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to turn that array of objects into an array of React components:

```
const Content = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
        {props.partArray.map((el, i) => <Part key={`part-${i}`} part={el.part} exercises={el.exercises}/>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

You may be wondering about that `key` prop. That helps React keep track of arrays of components when re-rendering. You can read more about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am also taking the same course. @Idtcoop has good solution.

But as per the level of course where it clearly says *"Our application passes on information in quite a primitive way at the moment, since it is based on individual variables. This situation will improve soon."* I think we have to do solution without modifying the variables. I guess that's the intention of the course.
Because later after 2 tasks, we are supposed to modify it to exactly what Idtcoop said,

> 1.4: course information step4 And then place the objects into an array. Modify the variable definitions of App into the following form
>   and modify the other parts of the application accordingly:

Loop is still not expected in this exercise too

> NB at this point you can assume that there are always three items, so
>   there is no need to go through the arrays using loops. We will come
>   back to the topic of rendering components based on items in arrays
>   with a more thorough exploration in the next part of the course.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function Header(props){
    return(
        <h1>{props.course}</h1>
    )
}

function Content(props){
    return(
        <div>
       <Part part={props.exercises.part1} exercise={props.exercises.exercises1}/>
       <Part part={props.exercises.part2} exercise={props.exercises.exercises2}/>
       <Part part={props.exercises.part3} exercise={props.exercises.exercises3}/>
       </div>
    )
}
function Total(props){
    return(
    <p>Number of exercises {props.total.exercises1 + props.total.exercises2 + props.total.exercises3}</p>
        )
}
function Part(props){
    return(
     <p>{props.part} {props.exercise}</p>
    )
}

function App(){
    // const defination for necessary information
    const course = "Half Stack application development"
    const part1 = "Fundamentals of React"
    const exercises1 = 10
    const part2 = 'Using props to pass data'
    const exercises2 = 7
    const part3 = 'State of a component'
    const exercises3 = 14

    return (
        <div>
           <Header course={course} />
           <Content exercises = {{part1:part1, exercises1:exercises1, part2:part2, exercises2:exercises2, part3:part3, exercises3: exercises3}} />
          <Total total={{exercises1:exercises1, exercises2:exercises2, exercises3:exercises3}} />

        </div>
    )

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```